# uiimageview how to display actual width and height

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

Hi I am displaying images in UIImageview and some images are small and some are big.

how to auto-display the images as per the actual width and height.?

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set imageview.frame to corresponding value (borrowed from UIImage.size).

Comment: how to set the uiimageview to the center of the screen so the resize wouldnt effect the position?

Comment: You should set imageview.center to the center of the screen (precise value depends on if status bar used, which is 20 pixels in height.)

Answer (score 0):

Set the UIImageView frame to be the size of the UIImage

Something like this

```
UIImage *aImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"];
yourImageView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, aImage.size.width, aImage.size.height);
```